# How to speed up this type of query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with words from a text (the table is called `token`), each word is a row in the table. I want to retrieve adjacent words in the result.

**Example:** `My name is Renato` must return:

```
My | name
name | is
is | Renato
```

The following query works, but is slow. The `textblockid` determines the text that the word belongs, the `sentence` is the sentence count in the textblock (but at the moment the value is 1 for all) and the `position` attribute determines the order of the words.

```
select w1.text,w2.text 
from token as w1,
    (select textblockid,sentence,position,text from token
    order by textblockid,sentence,position) as w2
where w1.textblockid = w2.textblockid
and w1.sentence = w2.sentence
and w1.position = w2.position - 1
```

**Is there a better/faster way to do this?**

Comment: What is the purpose of the subselect?  Is there a reason you cannot do this with a regular inner join?

Comment: Problem 1: You're unnecessarily ordering the results in the subquery.  Problem 2: You're joining the tables in the WHERE clause instead of a JOIN clause. (Not sure if this is hurting performance but it is confusing at the least.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know postgresql in detail but for sure query could be simpler in sql server:

```
select w1.text,w2.text 
from token as w1, token as w2
where w1.textblockid = w2.textblockid
and w1.sentence = w2.sentence
and w1.position = w2.position - 1
```

(I think it is better to use simplest query and leave the rest for optimizer, which may be misleaded by your from subquery).

However if you have index on (textblockid, sentence, position) you really can't get anything more with sql.

Comment: `SELECT w1.text,w2.text 
      FROM token w1
      JOIN token w2 USING (sentence, textblockid)
     WHERE w1.position = w2.position - 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an `INNER JOIN` with a second instance of `token` performs better. But it all depends on the data types of your columns, and the indexes you have in place.

For example, if `sentence` is a text column, the comparison between `w1.sentence` and `w2.sentence` will probably be very expensive. If it's a numeric id (a foreign key to a `sentences` table), and if you have an index on the column, it should be way faster. Assuming this last scenario, you could try this:

```
select w1.text,w2.text 
from token as w1
    INNER JOIN token as w2
    ON w2.sentence = w1.sentence
    AND w1.position = w2.position - 1
    AND w1.textblockid = w2.textblockid
```

Comment: It may be that sentence is not unique, but rather, the sentence is a value that is the index into the text;  In fact, that's how I would interpret them;  Stated another way, I assume the key is (textblockid, sentence) not (sentence).

Comment: The sentence is not foreign key neither unique. The sentence is only the sentence position/count. First sentence, second, third, forth, ...

Comment: Okay then. I'll edit my post to add the reference to `textblockid` back. Do you have an index on `sentence` anyway?